# Methods for Finding A Representative of Each Element in a Quotient Set $S/G$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

**Question**:

Let $G$ be a group and $S$ be a $G$-set. I am interested in finding a representative for each orbit in the quotient set $S/G$, especially in cases with an infinite number of orbits, i.e., the size of $S/G$ is infinite.

Are there any general techniques that can deal with this task?

**Thoughts**:

For a finite number of orbits, I can enumerate all orbits one by one and canonically select one representative for each orbit. A simple case is that $S$ forms a homogeneous space of $G$ possessing only a single orbit, e.g., I can choose the zero point for the $n$-dimensional translation group $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am stuck for an infinite number of orbits. The trivial idea is to find the invariants so elements in each orbit share one invariant, e.g., eigenvalues of symmetric matrices w.r.t. orthogonal group. However, that invariant might not belong to the orbit, so a representative cannot be selected.

I am new to group theory :). Any insights, references, or suggestions for further reading would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No.  For example, we need to appeal to AC for the existence of a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Comment: Think on how to use the Axiom of Choice! A good place to start would be to see the Wiki article: [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice)

Comment: @MathRookie2204 Thanks for your suggestions! I am sorry that I am unfamiliar with this, and I will read it!

Comment: "I can canonically select" is an oxymoron. For a selection process to be canonical, the representative should be selected by the data alone. An example in geometry is Hodge theorem, in which the metric on a Riemannian manifold canonically selects for each cohomology class a closed form. This form is obtained by solving an energy minimization problem which is defined relative to the metric. So in the case that you had no metric and were only on a smooth manifold, you would get no canonical representative for the cohomology class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no general techniques. This is an extremely general situation and encodes many difficult problems as special cases. For example, let $\pi$ be any group, let $G = GL_n(F)$ where $F$ is a field, and consider the action of $G$ on $\text{Hom}(\pi, G)$ by pointwise conjugation. Orbits of this action are isomorphism classes of $n$-dimensional linear representations of $\pi$ over $F$, and in general these are impossible to classify. This already occurs for $\pi = F_2$ the free group on two generators, where we want to classify pairs of invertible matrices up to simultaneous conjugation; this is called a ["wild"](https://leuschke.org/uploads/Research/SU-wildhyps.pdf) classification problem.

Even when we know how to solve this problem, say for $\pi = \mathbb{Z}$ where rational canonical form gives an answer, the solution isn't by applying a fully general technique and requires some real thought about the specific situation.

Even harder-looking classification problems can be described in this way, e.g. we can take $G = GL_n(F)$ again and consider its action by conjugation on the set of Lie brackets on $F^n$; then orbits of this action are isomorphism classes of $n$-dimensional Lie algebras over $F$, and this classification problem is also known to be wild once $n \ge 7$ or something like that. Similarly we can take $G = S_n$ and consider its action by relabeling on the set of labeled graphs on $n$ vertices; then orbits of this action are isomorphism classes of graphs on $n$ vertices so we have to solve [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism).

(In general, if you have a way to find canonical orbit representatives then you have a way to determine whether two elements belong to the same orbit, so e.g. in our examples above, a way to determine whether two linear representations are isomorphic, whether two Lie algebras are isomorphic, whether two graphs are isomorphic. The set of canonical orbit representatives itself then describes the orbit space, so this is a strictly harder problem than finding an "explicit" description of the orbit space.)

Also I don't agree with this:

> For a finite number of orbits, I can enumerate all orbits one by one and canonically select one representative for each orbit.

If $\pi$ is finitely generated above and $G = GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ then we are considering the orbits of a finite group acting on a finite set but no choices *canonically* present themselves by virtue of finiteness alone. Suppose $\pi = F_2$ as above; what are your canonical orbit representatives for, say, pairs of invertible $10 \times 10$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_7$ up to simultaneous conjugation? Similarly for graph isomorphism.