# Existence of $G$-Invariant Mappings in a Homogeneous Space

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

**Question**: I am currently exploring the concept of $G$-invariant mappings within the homogeneous $G$-spaces. Consider a group $G$ and a homogeneous space $M$ where $G$ acts upon it transitively. I am interested in understanding the conditions under which a $G$-invariant mapping $f:M\rightarrow M$ can exist. A mapping $f$ is termed $G$-invariant if it satisfies the relation $f(g\cdot x) = f(x)$ for all $g\in G$, $x\in M$.

**Thoughts**: This $G$-invariant mapping is also called [canonicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form), though its form varies wildly across different contexts. For instance, in the case of a diagonalizable square matrix, canonicalization under the orthogonal group is achieved through eigendecomposition. In contrast, for a graph under the action of a permutation group, canonicalization involves graph isomorphism, a notably more complex process. The feasibility of obtaining canonicalization is not always assured for me.

In my opinion, the existence of such a mapping $f$ may depend on the ability to uniquely identify one element in $M$. However, it is not clear to me if there exists a rigorous mathematical framework to characterize this "uniqueness" feature. It also remains unclear to me how this "uniqueness" concept interplays with other mathematical notions.

Any insights, references, or suggestions for further reading would be greatly appreciated.

Related Post: [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765444/methods-for-finding-a-representative-of-each-element-in-a-quotient-set-s-g)]

Comment: Every constant map is $G$-invariant, isn't it?

Comment: @freakish Hi, $f$ is mapping $x$ to the same domain $M$ where $x$ lies, and I don't think a constant always exists in the domain $M$. The domain $M$ maybe a set of matrices, manifolds, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "a constant doesn't always exist"? Literally pick any $c \in M$ and for any $x\in M$ define $f(x)=c$. Here "constant" doesn't refer to number, it can be anything, a fixed point, matrix, manifold, doughnut, anything that doesn't change. A single valued function.

Comment: Where exactly do you see a contradiction? Why picking a single element from $M$ is a problem?

Comment: @freakish I finally went it through. I think this problem is different from my previous post (representative, as we were required to pick one that is different from the others). And a constant map indeed suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be homogenous and $f$ a $G$-invariant function with $M$ as its domain (its range doesn't even have to be $M$, it is not relevant). If $x,y\in M$ then there is $g\in G$ such that $y=gx$. And thus $f(y)=f(gx)=f(x)$. By the arbitrary choice of $x,y$ we conclude that $f$ depends only on a single value $f(x)$, i.e. it is constant.

And vice versa, you can easily verify that every constant function is $G$-invariant.

And so, for the homogenous case it is not really interesting: being $G$-invariant is the same as being constant.

More generally $f:X\to Y$ is $G$-invariant if and only if $f$ restricted to each orbit is constant. It just happens that "is homogenous" means "has one orbit".